# Latex interprets an [x] at the start of a new line as a unit of measurment with x being a number. How do I Stop it from doing it?

Tags: latex

So I have a simple text I want to render in latex:\

```
\section{Source}
[1] Some text\\
[2] \href{A Text}{A Link to a Website}\\
[3] \href{Another Text}{Another Link to a Website}\\
[4] \href{A 3rd Text}{A 3rd Link to a Website}
```

The compiler throws the error "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)" for the 2nd and 4th line and compiles only the line with [1] correctly and leave away the [2], [3] and [4] at the following lines. I know that with {} I can use \{ and \} to get them but how can I make that for [] now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't abuse `\\`  for line breaks (with the exception of tabulars etc.)

In your case this is not only bad style but causes an error because latex interprets the `[]` after it as optional argument and expects the amount of vertical space to be inserted instead of just a plain number.

You could either use proper paragraphs by leaving empty lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}

\section{Source}
[1] Some text

[2] \href{A Text}{A Link to a Website}

[3] \href{Another Text}{Another Link to a Website}

[4] \href{A 3rd Text}{A 3rd Link to a Website}


\end{document}
```

or if your whole document consists of such lines, you could make latex respect them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}


\begin{document}

\obeylines

\section{Source}
[1] Some text
[2] \href{A Text}{A Link to a Website}
[3] \href{Another Text}{Another Link to a Website}
[4] \href{A 3rd Text}{A 3rd Link to a Website}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's answer. I would also recommend using LaTeX-specific structuring, e.g., the `enumerate` environment.

Still, for a direct answer, you may group the mis-interpreted `[`, `]` inside curly brackets

```latex
[1] Some text \\
{[2]}\href{A Text}{A Link to a Website}\\
{[3]}\href{Another Text}{Another Link to a Website}\\
{[4]}\href{A 3rd Text}{A 3rd Link to a Website}
```

Also, you can use `\lbrack` and `\rbrack` as replacements for `[` and `]`.

Comment: Please read https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66499/36296 Showing the OP how to keep using `\\ ` is like helping them to shoot themself in the foot.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I began my answer by stating that I agree with your answer, I did not validate OP's choices... Still, one may encounter this problem with square brackets interpreted as arguments in other contexts, where it is valid, since it has nothing to do with the newline per se, but just with the previous command (witch happens to be `\newline` -- for some reason not yet deleted from any LaTeX version)